# Slicing a MultiIndex DataFrame with a condition based on the index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']), np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
df = pd.DataFrame([[24, 13,  8,  9],
   [11, 30,  7, 23],
   [21, 31, 12, 30],
   [ 2,  5, 19, 24],
   [15, 18,  3, 16],
   [ 2, 24, 28, 11],
   [23,  9,  6, 12],
   [29, 28, 11, 21]], index=arrays, columns=list('abcd'))


df
          a   b   c   d
bar one  24  13   8   9
    two  11  30   7  23
baz one  21  31  12  30
    two   2   5  19  24
foo one  15  18   3  16
    two   2  24  28  11
qux one  23   9   6  12
    two  29  28  11  21
```

I want to slice the dataframe such that the results contains all rows which have `foo` as value for their first index and all the rows which have `bar` as first level index and `two` as second level index.
I.e. the resulting dataframe shoud look like this:

```
          a   b   c   d
bar two  11  30   7  23
foo one  15  18   3  16
    two   2  24  28  11
```

One way to get this result is

```
pd.concat([df.loc[[('bar', 'two')],:], df.loc[('foo', slice(None)),:]])
```

but this feels like a very cumbersome way,  there must be a more "pythonic" way..

Comment: why not just reset_index :-)

Comment: @Wen I just thought that there must be a way to get the results just by using the .loc / .xs methods but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`query` to the rescue:

```
df.query('ilevel_0 == "foo" or (ilevel_0 == "bar" and ilevel_1 == "two")')

          a   b   c   d
bar two  11  30   7  23
foo one  15  18   3  16
    two   2  24  28  11
```

`xs`, `loc`, etc all fail because your slicing across levels is not consistent.

Comment: Using pandas for year, never head of `.query'.  Is there a way to name to indices s.t. these names can be used instead of 'ilevel_0', 'ilevel_1' etc.?

Comment: @crs Sure, use `df = df.rename_axis(['name1', 'name2'])` and you can substitute ilevel_* with your names.

Answer (score 7):

You can use default slicing

```
l0 = df.index.get_level_values(0)
l1 = df.index.get_level_values(1)
cond = (l0 == "foo") | ((l0=="bar") & (l1=="two"))
df[cond]
```

Output

```
        a   b   c   d
bar two 11  30  7   23
foo one 15  18  3   16
    two 2   24  28  11
```